# Mac OS WebView Underline Spelling Errors

Tags: macos, webview, spell-checking

I have a simple problem with that is proving to be terribly difficult to find an answer for. I am using a WebView to load a webpage with text areas. When typing in these text areas spelling mistakes are not appearing with the traditional red underline, however, the spell correct guesses are showing up in the contextual menu when you right click on the work.

Answer (score 1):

Use setContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled on your WebView. Call this sometime after you load the URL, like so:

```
...
NSString *url = @"http://www.google.com";
[[myview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];

[myview setContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled:YES];
...
```